# MySql Calculate Grouped Fields Percentage and Show on one row

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, percentage

```
+--------+--------+--------+------------+
| line | field1 | count|
| x |    a | 2 |
| x |    b | 2 |
| x |    c | 1 |
| y |    a | 1 |
| y |    b | 1 |
| y |    c | 1 |
| y |    d|  1 |
```

As you can see above table represented line is grouped field, I try to get query result something like that or similiar:

```
+--------+--------+--------+------------+
| line | field1-percentage|
| x |  a-%40,b-%40,c-%20 |
| y |  a-%25,b-%25,c-%20 |
```

Comment: What does "something like that or similar" mean?  You've dumped a lot of values into a string, which is not really a recommended data structure.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: So Can you explain, there are too many line values, and i want show the percentage's of these lines according to count.

Answer (score 0):

Column names altered (`count` is [Reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-C)).

For MySQL 8+ use

```sql
WITH cte AS ( SELECT category, entity, SUM(amount) amount
              FROM test
              GROUP BY category, entity WITH ROLLUP )
SELECT category, GROUP_CONCAT(t1.entity, '-%', ROUND(100 * t1.amount / t2.amount)) percentage
FROM cte t1
JOIN cte t2 USING (category)
WHERE t2.entity IS NULL
GROUP BY category;
```

For MySQL 5.x use:

```sql
SELECT category, GROUP_CONCAT(t1.entity, '-%', ROUND(100 * t1.amount / t2.amount)) percentage
FROM ( SELECT category, entity, SUM(amount) amount
       FROM test
       GROUP BY category, entity ) t1
JOIN ( SELECT category, SUM(amount) amount
       FROM test
       GROUP BY category ) t2 USING (category)
GROUP BY category;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7cdd5cd63465b49c5a0f800791623593)